# VBox shared folder cp: cannot create directory '$dir': Protocol Error

Tags: linux, directory, centos, virtualbox, shared-directory

So i am trying to cp a file into my vbox shared folder and it will not let me. The vboxsf is mounted (as I can cd into the dir and ls and see dir/files), the user is added to the group (vim /etc/group vboxsf shows vboxsf:x:493:$USER). What am I missing to copy from guest to host

Guest: Centos 6
Host: Centos 7

Comment: VBox can also mount directories as read only.

Comment: "Protocol Error" is an odd error to get if the problem is permissions. Is the mounted path a normal directory (not a symlink, sshfs mount, etc.)?

Comment: Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/), [**Server Fault**](http://serverfault.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).